# What are these 1x2 clip and bar pieces?

Tags: part-identification, bricklink

I am not sure what this piece is and I need to know what it's called so I can find it on BrickLink.

[image: pieces]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those pieces are:

[Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Handle on Side - Free Ends](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2540)

[image: Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Handle on Side - Free Ends]

And

[Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip Horizontal on End](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63868)

[image: Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip Horizontal on End]